# Kali Virtualbox (on macOS) won't connect to internet over NAT

Tags: networking, macos, virtualbox, kali-linux

I am currently running Kali as a virtualbox on my Mac. I want to have it set up so that the VM can access the internet, as well as being connected to the host OS (so I can connect over SSH, etc.)

Currently, `Adapter 2` is host only, and is working fine. I can SSH into Kali from my host OS. `Adapter 1` is set up as a NAT, but it is not working and so I cannot connect to the internet.

When I do `ping google.com`, I get:

```
ping: google.com: Name or service not known
```

On Kali I have the following settings in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
    address 10.0.2.15
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.2.2

allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.100.101
    netmask 255.255.255.0
```

`eth1` is the `Adapter 2 (Host-Only)`

Also, the results of `route -n` are:

[image: result route -n]

Does my issue lie in the addresses I have given `eth0`? Where have I gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found your post while looking for an answer to my own question. I believe you’ll need to install the appropriate firmware to connect via wireless. My install prompted that I required some non-free firmware for networking. Perhaps this will help.

Comment: (1) Where does the question say anything about wireless? (It’s talking about interfaces `eth0` and `eth1`.) (2) You believe that *firmware* is the solution to a problem *with a **virtual machine**?*